# Steam/Tf2 crash

Tags: steam, technical-issues, team-fortress-2

After the last Team Fortress 2 update, i can't exit steam, i can't play the game, i can't uninstall the game and it seams like my account is gone: when they ask for account information(username and password) I put in the information but it doesn't work even if the information, is in the steam account that i can't exit. I have tried everything i could in my power, but nothing works.

Please help...

Comment: Try on [Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/).

Comment: RESTART. your computer.

Answer (score 3):

Try logging into the [Steam Store](http://store.steampowered.com) or [Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com) websites.
A similar issue has happened to me and after logging into the website when I realized it was just a server issue preventing me from logging into the Steam Client, as the Steam servers go offline from time to time for scheduled maintainance.

Might just have to be patient if you can login to the website but not into the client.